# Gradle/Android How to append parameter to urls when resolving dependency?

Tags: maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, repository

I hosted my maven repository in http://1.2.3.4/me/maven/master/

And I've set the repository in build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven{
            url = "http://1.2.3.4/me/maven/master/"
        }
    }
}
```

And 'com.test:test-library:1.0.1@aar' is one of the dependency needed for the project

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.test:test-library:1.0.1@aar'
}
```

When project is building, it lookups http://1.2.3.4/me/maven/master/com/test/test-library/1.0.0/test-library-1.0.0.pom for metadata

My problem is how can I overwrite the url so that it appends parameter to end of the path for every network request to http://1.2.3.4/me/maven/master/, like:

```
http://1.2.3.4/me/maven/master/com/test/test-library/1.0.0/test-library-1.0.0.pom?token=xxxxxxxx
```

I need the token to access files.